# USB Voltage auto selector (Prioritise VUSB)

Tags: usb, switches, voltage-regulator

I'm trying to design a auto voltage selector circuit to prioritise USB voltage when the USB is plugged in. The power goes through some voltage regulators which then powers a MCU (ATMEGA32U). I have two circuits for this, one that goes to the 3.3 V voltage regulator and another that goes to a 5 V voltage regulator. VIN varies from 3.7 V to 15 V.

**Voltage selector for 3.3 V**

[image]

When there is no VUSB present the P-Channel MOSFET allows current to go through from VIN. When VUSB is present, it turns on the P-channel MOSFET which blocks the current from VIN and allows the current flow through via the diode. The switch is just there so that I can bypass this entire circuit if necessary.

**Voltage selector for 5 V**

[image]

Similar to before when no VUSB is present, the P-Channel MOSFET allows current to go through from VIN. When VUSB is present, it turns on the P-Channel MOSFET which block the current from VIN and allows current to flow through to the 5 V rail bypassing the voltage regulator via the diode.

Is there any problem with this circuit and will it work? I know there are similar questions like this before but none has been exactly what I need.

Comment: The body diodes in your FETs always conduct if Vin is above Vusb so your schematic does not work.

Comment: Have you considered using a power mux? Like the [TPS2112](http://www.ti.com/product/TPS2112).